SSRS Rpt Builder: is there a way to search a large text field for specific text and return that text and everything after it until a period is found?
In SSRS/Report Builder, I need to search a large text field for a specific value, and return that value and return everything to the right of that value until a period is found.
For example, I have a large text field and I need to search for the text 'Business Requirement IDs:' inside this field and return this  text and everything after it until a period is found.
So if the text field value is
"Beginning of text.  Business Requirement IDs: 01-Export Data to Excel, 02-Export Data to PDF. Rest of text field" 

then I only want to return
"Business Requirement IDs: 01-Export Data to Excel, 02-Export Data to PDF"

Do I need to break this down into two parts? i.e, first search for the txt value and return everything to the right of it and then a second field to extract everything from this field until a period is found?

Look at MID() and INSTR() functions. Break down the problems into smaller bits. 1. Find position of the starting string "Business req...". 2. look for the first instance of a "." but starting at the position we found in 1.. 3. now you have your two positions extract that text using MID(), the start argument will be expression used in 1. the length argument will be difference between the expr. used in 2. and expr 1. . I'm sure there are dozens of answers out there .

That worked perfectly.  Thank yout
